# getting too many arguments error in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
customer(chuchi, goyal, 800.00).
customer(rishu, jain, 900.00).

get_cust_bal(X, Y, Z):-
    customer(chuchi, Y, 800.00),
    customer(X, Y, Z),
    format('owes me Bal ~w', [X, Y, Z]).
```

the error is

```
Format error: too many arguments
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] format('owes me Bal ~w',[_4304,goyal|...])
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1162
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Comment: Try `format('owes me Bal ~w', [[X, Y, Z]])`.

Comment: yes it did but i just simply wrote     write(X),tab(1),
    write(Y), tab(1), format('~w is the amount owed to me', [Z]).

Comment: Have you read the docs?